# Any good Expression Blend Tutorial out there?

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

i want to learn Expression blend.. ive been reading some blogs.. about it.. but the applications are some what hard to follow cuse i haven't had a crash course on Blend.. any good tutorial to learn the basics?? i think i need to learn XAML first..what do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Jesse Liberty's [Silverlight video tutorial series](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials.aspx), which includes a couple of videos on Expression Blend. Learning XAML will be very beneficial to you, although is not absolutely required to use Expression Blend.

Answer (score 3):

I also have a series of [written Blend tutorials](http://visitmix.com/labs/rosetta/eyesofblend/) available, that I'd like to humbly offer. They were written as an introduction to Silverlight through Blend, demonstrating the areas where Blend can be more useful than Visual Studio.

Comment: As a quick disclaimer, I didn't search through looking for a post to pimp my tutorials. This thread just came up as a Google Web Alert for Blend, which seems a bit late now.

Comment: 8y later, tutorials gone :/

Answer (score 2):

Check out my Button tutorial for beginners here.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/expression/ExpressionBlendButtons.aspx

More to follow...

Hope this helps,

Alan

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have some videos up on their Expression site as well. Seem fairly comprehensive:

[Linkies](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197141.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

there's nice course for beginners by kirupa. it gives overall idea for beginners.

http://www.kirupa.com/net/getting_started_blend.htm

Comment: link to kirupa links to Microsoft site where you land on download - not a tutorial (5y later)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a really nice course by Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/school/

Comment: link does not work anymore (6y later ;))

Answer (score 0):

Total Training have a fabulous array of Expression courses covering most products and versions